# How do I assign a value to a whole array of integers?

Tags: delphi

I know I can do that:

```
const
  arrayOfIntegers : Array[1..15] of Integer = (3,2,8,10,1,6,2,13,13,3,13,13,13,3,45);
```

But how can I do the following instead?

```
var
  arrayOfIntegers : Array[1..15] of Integer;
begin
  arrayOfIntegers := (3,2,8,10,1,6,2,13,13,3,13,13,13,3,45);
end;
```

As soon as I try to compile the code above I get E2029 ')' expected but ',' found

Comment: If you used a dynamic array you could use the dyn array constructor. Here you can declare a const and then assign it to your variable.

Comment: In addition to David's "const-and-assign" approach, you have to declare a new type and use it for the array const and var to make this work. Declaring both as `Array[1..15] of Integer` will lead to an "incompatible type" error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A typical use will be the following:

```
type
  TIntegerArray1to15 = Array[1..15] of Integer;
const
  INIT_INT_1_15_ARRAY: TIntegerArray1to15 = (3,2,8,10,1,6,2,13,13,3,13,13,13,3,45);

var
  arrayOfIntegers : TIntegerArray1to15;
begin
  arrayOfIntegers := INIT_INT_1_15_ARRAY;
  .... use and update arrayOfIntegers[]
end;
```

You should better define your own type in this case (code won't be slower or bigger, and you'll be able to make assignments between instances of this type). And you'll ensure that your array boundaries will be as expected (1..15).

The `const` statement will be compiled as a "reference" array, which will be copied in your `arrayOfIntegers` local variable. I've made it uppercase, which a somewhat commmon usage when declaring constants (but not mandatory - this is just a personal taste).

If you want your code to be more generic and reusable (which IMHO makes sense if you want to be a lazy programmer) you may rely on *dynamic arrays*, and/or `array of const` parameters (if your array start with index 0).

Answer (score 13):

You didn't mention what Delphi version you're using but in the modern Delphi you can do something like this:

```
var
  arrayOfIntegers : TArray<Integer>;
begin
  arrayOfIntegers := TArray<Integer>.Create(3,2,8,10,1,6,2,13,13,3,13,13,13,3,45);
end;
```

Comment: Note that this will be a 0-based array instead of the originally 1-based.

Comment: Yes, it will be. That's why it is always better to use Low() and High() when looping arrays to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Linas Can you use `for i := low(arrayOfIntegers) to high(arrayOfIntegers) do` - I'm not sure it will even compile. I guess you should better, on modern version of Delphi use `for aInteger in arrayOfIntegers do`

Comment: @Linas Should not the `arrayOfInteger` be freed after use? If yes, you may consider change your code not to be misleading someone.

Comment: @Arnaud, if you downvoted me then I suggest you to start working with more recent Delphi versions to know them better. "<code>for i := low(arrayOfIntegers) to high(arrayOfIntegers) do<code>" is proper way to loop and if you didn't know you do not need to free arrays in Delphi.

Comment: @Arnaud `TArray<Integer>` is simply a dynamic array. It's the same as `array of Integer`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan @Linas Thanks for the input. I did not use this syntax usually (since I want my code to be compiled in most Delphi versions, including FPC). That's why my comments were in form of questions, not assertions. What was worrying me is the fact that dynamic arrays or `TArray<Integer>`  are 0-based, and not the same as `Array[1..15] of Integer`. Plain static arrays still exists and have their meaning! In all cases, I'm happy having learn something, thanks to you all.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax used in the const section is only valid for typed array constants. You cannot use it as a literal array constant in an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of assign a value to a whole array of integers

```
const
  C_ARR_COST : array ['a'..'e'] of string = ('01','02','03');
var Conter:Char;
begin
  //Loop
  for Conter := Low(C_ARR_COST) to high(C_ARR_COST) do
    ShowMessage(C_ARR_COST[Conter]);

  //Direct
  ShowMessage(C_ARR_COST['a']);
end;
```

Good luck.